# C2664 conversion error

Tags: c++, mfc, int, c2664

I am a beginner in programming language and need your help.
I have got codes from C language which is needed to be written into C++ MFC.

In C language I have codes like int32 float64 and when I put them into MFC application, they showed this error.

```
error C2664: cannot convert parameter 5 from 'float [1000]' to 'float64 []' 
error C2664: cannot convert parameter 7 from 'int *' to 'int32 *'
```

How do I convert from int32/float64 to just int/float type codes?
Any kind help will do.
Thank You

PS. May I know what is the * behind the int32* means??

Comment: The * behind the `int32` means that it is a pointer to an `int32` rather than an `int32` itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I know int32 means that it is a 32 bit integer, meaning 4 bytes.

If I were you I would have used the sizeof inbuilt function to check the size of int on your machine and then proceed from there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models

if the sizes are equal on your machine then you can use static_cast to cast int32 to an int variable type.